# Visual Studio and Clang Different Behavior Template Metaprogramming

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, namespaces, clang

The following files do compile on both Visual Studio compiler and Clang for Microsoft Codegen, however the result is wildly different.

In Visual Studio it counts the amount of dynamic matrices in the parameter list (which is my intended behaviour). Instead in clang it counts the number of dynamic matrices until the first static matrix is encountered. (The output is in the main.cpp file, in the format (VS, Clang))

I was also able to replicate on gcc 7.1 and icc 17, which both follow the same behaviour of clang

Removing the `meta` namespace as weel as adding an `using` declaration resolves the issue, but I can't figure out why

[Working example (cl 2017 RTW vs gcc 7.1)](https://godbolt.org/g/QvEAGq)

[Pastebin for ease of use](https://pastebin.com/74NwfQ2n)

```
#include <tuple>

template <size_t x = 0>
class M{};

template <>
class M<0>{};

// Note, if this is removed the problem disappears
namespace meta
{
    inline auto f()
    {
        return std::make_tuple();
    }

    template <std::size_t x, typename ... Args>
    auto f(const M<x>& , Args && ... args)
    {
        return f(args...);
    }

    template <typename ... Args>
    auto f(const M<>& first, Args && ... args)
    {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(first), f(args...));
    }
}

#include <iostream>


int main(int, char* [])
{

    M<1> a;
    M<> b;

    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(a, a, a))>::value << "\n"; // (0, 0)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(a, a, b))>::value << "\n"; // (1, 0)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(a, b, a))>::value << "\n"; // (1, 0)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(a, b, b))>::value << "\n"; // (2, 0)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(b, a, a))>::value << "\n"; // (1, 1)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(b, a, b))>::value << "\n"; // (2, 1)
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<decltype(meta::f(b, b, b))>::value << "\n"; // (3, 3)

}
```

## Output Visual Studio

```
0
1
1
2
1
2
3
```

## Output clang/gcc/icc

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
3
```

Comment: What's the result? What did you expect? Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Rakete1111 Added for more clarity

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Many things, but maybe it's just me. The indentation at the beginning. The namespaces. The macro guards. All of the doxygen? comments. You don't need all that stuff.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I am sorry about the indentation mess, the stackoverflow editor didn't let me submit the code until I created this single file atrocity, The pastebin is what ideally the code submitted would have looked like. I kept the namespaces because I believe they might have an effect on the behaviour, even though I could be wrong

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I was mainly referring to the fact that the output is missing, maybe with the differences highlighted or something. Just so that the question is easier to read.

Comment: I reviewed this code once more, and now I agree with Rakete completly - you definitely should trim the code much more. It will make the analysis easier, and also it will allow you to narrow the scope of the problem. Right now the setup is quite complex, especially with the two-faces of the MatrixBase base template. Please try to get rid of that, jsut for the same of diagnosing why `get_dynamic_matrices` does not work.

Comment: `get_dynamic_matrices` is relatively simple. You should be able to test it on simple items too, like, a simple plain `class MatrixDynamic` and `class MatrixStatic` should be enough to verify if this function works the same way on compilerA and compilerB. Maybe there's a difference even on such simple setup with no CRTP-base-class noise?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl surprising as it may, by removing the CRTP base class and the meta namespace the problem disappears, which honestly baffles me

Comment: sadly, these parts are one of the most complex ones in the type system.. you probably hit into a compiler bug

Comment: hm.. but then.. base class is quite a unrelated thing here.. is it just the base class you removed? nothing more?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I had removed the meta namespace as well, now by putting it back and removing the base class the problem resurfaced, so the meta namespace must somehow be the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had opened a [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=33588) on clang, and it was extremely quickly revealed this is indeed a bug, only not in clang but in MSVC. I am going to shamelessly steal Richard Smith's answer here:

> This is an MSVC bug, due to their missing / incorrect implementation
>   of two-phase name lookup.
>
> Within the second definition of f:
>
> ```
> template <std::size_t x, typename ... Args>
> auto f(const M<x>& , Args && ... args)
> {
>     return f(args...);
> }
> ```
>
> ... the third 'f' has not yet been declared and thus is not found by
>   unqualified name lookup. So once the recursion reaches this overload,
>   it can never "go back" to the third overload.
>
> If the namespace is removed, the third overload can be found by
>   argument-dependent name lookup.